# How to combine two classes?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code for a vaccination certificate using the class function in python. I know I need a class for patients and a class for vaccines, but I do not know how to link the two together or if I need an extra class for that. I need to be able to input users to check if they have a certificate. No GUI, just terminal based mock up code.

```
class Vaccination():

    def _init_(self,  ID, name, Vdate, address):
        self.ID = ID
        self.name = name
        self.Vdate =Vdate
        self.address = address

    def AstraZeneca(self):
        return ID


AstraZeneca = Vaccination("123","AstraZeneca","23/06/2021","Male","Robert-Koch")


class Patient(object):

    def _init_(self, ID, name, bdate, gender, phone, address):
        self.ID = ID
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.bdate = bdate
        self.gender = gender
        self.address = address

    def get_name(self):
```

I got stuck at this point. I am out of ideas on how to make this work using classes.

Comment: If you just want to be able to track vaccination records in a simple, toy way, a dictionary of patient IDs mapping to an instance of a `Vaccination` class should suffice

Comment: You could have an list member in `Patient`, collecting `Vaccination`s, empty at the beginning.

Comment: It's not clear from how you've typed it, but `__init__` has two underscores on each side ("dunder" function). You might also check your indentation, as Python is very dependent on the proper indentation for its code.

Comment: Code aside, think of the relationship of each entity. I think the easiest to explain this is that each patient has a vaccination (or not). Knowing that, you will know what object needs to reside within another.
In this case, each patient should have instance(s) of Vaccination as a member of it. In this case, the vaccine itself doesn't need patient-specific members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some mistakes in your code I have fixed. I want to propose this relation, where a `Patient` *has one* `Vaccination`. By default, the patient hasn't been vaccinated, you can see that in the `Patient` constructor (`vaccine` is `None` by default):

```
class Vaccination(object):

    def __init__(self, ID, name, Vdate, address):
        self.ID = ID
        self.name = name
        self.Vdate =Vdate
        self.address = address

    def AstraZeneca(self):
        return self.ID


class Patient(object):

    def __init__(self, ID, name, bdate, gender, phone, address, vaccine=None):
        self.ID = ID
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.bdate = bdate
        self.gender = gender
        self.address = address
        self.vaccine = vaccine

    def get_name(self):
      print(self.name)

# An astrazeneca
astrazeneca = Vaccination('1', 'Astrazeneca', '23/06/2023', 'An address')

# Jhon Doe has been vaccined with astrazeneca
patient_1 = Patient('123','Jhon Doe','23/06/1998','Male', '3345556', 'An address', astrazeneca)

# Some else hasn't been vaccined yet.
patient_2 = Patient('123','Some Else','23/06/1978','Male', '56456', 'An address2')

# Here you can access the Jhon Doe's vaccine id
# Although, If I were you I'd change the name method for something like get_id()
print(patient_1.vaccine.AstraZeneca())
```

If a `Patient` has been vaccinated, then `vaccine` param will be a `Vaccination` object, otherwise, it will be `None`.

Finally, I recommend you to read about [relations among classes](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3029325/exploring-association-aggregation-and-composition-in-oop.html) in OOP. The example above is a Composition, it's a kind of relation used in this paradigm.

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful.

Comment: Can I improve this code further by using a dictionary for the patients? I want to use the input method to check for all users whose details are in the dictionary

Comment: @Autchman I think you can do another question in SO, but this time, I recommend you give more details about what you want to improve, how many tries you have done, and put the code in the question. Btw ... if you consider this answer responds to the original question about how to relate two classes, you could mark it as correct using ✓. The above help others to find the answer easier on the platform and help me to grow in SO too :)

Answer (score 0):

First, I think

```
AstraZeneca = Vaccination("123","AstraZeneca","23/06/2021","Male","Robert-Koch")
```

is wrong. Based on your code it should be

```
AstraZeneca = Patient("123","AstraZeneca","23/06/2021","Male","Robert-Koch")
```

To link two classes, you need something to match, let's say you have a `vaccination_type` in `Patient` which is the **name** of a `Vaccination`, you can do something like this.

```
vaccination_list = [] # Append Vaccination Object into this list

def find_certificate_via_patient(patient):
    for vaccination in vaccination_list:
        if patient.vaccination_type in vaccination.name:
            return vaccination
        print("No Vaccination Found")
```